# How to allow attachment to be displayed in a iframe

Tags: html, iframe, sharepoint, attachment

I want to display an attachment in a iframe, I tried adding `<WebPartPages:AllowFraming runat:"server"/>` in the Master Page but it didn't work, do you have any suggestions about how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the full path for your attachment.

```
<ac:structured-macro ac:name="html"><ac:plain-text-body><![CDATA[<iframe src="http://YOURDOMAIN/path_to_file" noborder="0" width="830" height="800" scrolling="yes" seamless></iframe>]]></ac:plain-text-body></ac:structured-macro>
```

Hope it Helps